# How to set Text of a Textbox with type= "password" in code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have to set user's current password in a textbox like (********)

**In HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" type="password" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="ChangePassword"
                        MaxLength="30"></asp:TextBox>
```

**In Code Behind**

```
txtPassword.Text = "admin123";
```

Its not setting the value. Whereas, if I remove `type="password"` it works but that is plain text.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this is changing the textmode before and after assigning value.Then it will work fine

```
txtPassword.Attributes["type"] = "text";
txtPassword.Text = password;
txtPassword.Attributes["type"] = "password";
```

Answer (score 3):

The marked answer did not work for me, but the following method did work, that I found [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Set-TextBox-value-when-TextMode-is-Password-ASPNet.aspx).

```
txtPassword.Attributes["value"] = "admin123";
```

Hope this helps others too

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego: these comments are getting to be rather off-topic, but where in that post does it say anything about when linked information should be included? The central guidelines on that are here: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370). If you removed the link, *is this an answer*? You can edit it down to *The following method worked for me, `code`* where the link part could be attached as *which I found at [linked page]*. The link is just *attribution*, nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

<asp:TextBox> will be convert to <input type="password"... />
you can try this:
txtPassword.Value = "admin123";